# How to override configuration level "transitive = false" for one dependency

Tags: gradle, cucumber, build.gradle

I've inherited some code and want to add cucumber to the project, preferably changing as little as possible. But the gradle file has a configuration level setting to stop transitive dependencies being pulled in, which is causing cucumber-java to not pull in cucumber-core and therefore fail.

So here's the relevant parts of build.gradle:

```
configurations.all {
  transitive = false
}

depdendencies {
  compile(group: .... lots of these

  testCompile(group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java8', version: '4.8.0', transitive: true)
  testCompile(group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-testng', version: '4.8.0', transitive: true)
}
```

my hope was that the `transitive: true` would then override the configuration level but it doesn't work.

I have also tried adding:

```
configurations {
  all*.exclude group: 'io.cucumber', module: 'cucumber-java8'
}
```

but it then doesn't pull in this dependency at all

I'd prefer not to pull in all the dependencies for cucumber manually, and I'd rather not remove this configuration level `transitive = false`. Is it possible to do what I'm trying? Can I set the configuration just for `compile` dependencies? Or will I have to remove the configuration level setting and add `transitive: false` to every compile dependency?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
configurations {
 compile {
    transitive false
  }
 testCompile {
    transitive true
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that does the job, thanks! I tried this earlier with a slightly different format so think it didn't work.
I've actually set "transitive true" for testCompile and that seems to work, rather than set it to false then override it every time. I'd prefer to not have to set "transitive false" for each configuration, but there's only 5 or so for now so think this is gonna sort it
Thanks again